# How to fix Image elements do not have explicit width and height in gatsby?

Tags: reactjs, seo, lighthouse

PageSpeed Insights warning me: Set an explicit width and height on image elements to reduce layout shifts and improve CLS.

Answer (score 0):

I do not face this issue [here](https://pagespeed.web.dev/report?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.software-express.de%2F&form_factor=desktop).

The banner image:

```
<StaticImage className={styles.bannerImage} src="./kaspersky-banner-image.jpeg" alt="Kaspersky Alternativen Banner-Bild" />
```

The class:

```
.bannerImage {
  max-height: 30rem;
}
```